# VBA Excel Macro Error , Expected: list separator or )

Tags: excel, vba

I am a new user on Excel VBA, recently i encounter this error when ever i try to run my macro. What my macro do is by reading the cell row data and will create a chart by itself for export purpose, etc.

Below is my macro code

```
Sub CombinationChart()

    Dim lastrow As String
    Dim boundaryRow As String
    
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    lastrow = mySheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    boundaryRow = lastrow - 20
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("mySheet!$A$" & boundaryRow ":$B$" & lastrow)  'make sure the range is correct here
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine 'select which column should be the Line or the Column
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
End Sub
```

The error part is here

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("mySheet!$A$" & boundaryRow ":$B$" & lastrow)  'make sure the range is correct here
```

My last row variable is the last row which contains data in the excel table whereas boundaryRow is a variable who gets the last row value and subtract it by 20 which is last row - 20 , but i just cant look for a way to put in my two variables into my ActiveChart.Range.

Comment: @Joffan mySheet is the name of my worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the [concatenate operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-summary) (`&`) in your problem line.

Here is how it should look:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("mySheet!$A$" & boundaryRow & ":$B$" & lastrow)
```

`&` was missing between `boundaryRow` and `":$B$"`

Comment: & was missing, but it was missing *after* `boundaryRow` ;-)

Comment: @Joffan good pickup. What a silly error - I've edited to reflect.

Comment: No worries, just proof-reading habit. It's easy to forget exactly how something got fixed.

Comment: @SteveKush per [the someone answers page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please ensure you mark whichever answer has resolved your issue as 'accepted'. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do what you want with a `Range` object variable. I'm assuming here - since you use it to calculate `lastRow` - that you have `mySheet` defined as a `Worksheet` object (probably globally).

```
Sub CombinationChart()

    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim boundaryRow As Long
    Dim chartData as Range
     
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
    lastrow = mySheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'mySheet is defined elsewhere
    boundaryRow = lastrow - 20
    Set chartData = mySheet.Cells(boundaryRow,1).Resize(21,2) ' 21 rows x 2 columns

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=chartData  'make sure the range is correct here
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine 'select which column should be the Line or the Column
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
End Sub
```

You could do this "on the fly" too, substituting in the expression I have assigned to `chartData` to the `SetSourceData` `Source` parameter.

Comment: Would it be *more correct* for `lastrow` and `boundryRow` to be declared as `Long` rather than `String` (despite OP declarations)?

Comment: It absolutely would, and I am chagrined to have missed it.